# Use robust linear regression to find mean correlation between the columns of two dataframes

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

The `triplets` dataframe contains information regarding the correlation-pair, whereby the `target` column matches `rownames(exp_subset)`, while the `probeID` column matches `rownames(meth_subset)`.

I want to compute the column-wise mean correlation between the `meth_subset` and `exp_subset` dataframes based on the pairs identified in the `triplets` dataframe. I'm using robust linear regression.

```
library(foreign)
library(MASS)

meth <- as_tibble(diff.bval.all, rownames = "probeID")
exp <- as_tibble(exp, rownames = "target")
methexp <- bind_rows(meth, exp) %>% left_join(triplets)
meth_subset <- dplyr::select(methexp, all_of(names(meth)))
exp_subset <- dplyr::select(methexp, all_of(names(exp)))
meth_subset <- unlist(meth_subset)
exp_subset <- unlist(exp_subset)

meth_subset <- diff.bval.all[rownames(diff.bval.all) %in% triplets$probeID,]
exp_subset <- exp[rownames(exp) %in% triplets$target,]
corr <- sapply(seq(ncol(meth_subset)), function(i) rlm(meth_subset[, i] ~ exp_subset[, i]))
```

My code returned an empty `corr`.

```
> corr
list()
```

Input:

```
> dput(diff.bval.all[1:5,1:5])
structure(c(0.840969057327896, 0.893104855161159, 0.942661814974088, 
0.361039746108508, 0.919421313819497, 0.821544338967354, 0.920421860019175, 
0.915994356209978, 0.163126879872322, 0.982721527497647, 0.792123250515352, 
0.733797352806937, 0.917550839964633, 0.557177093393426, 0.956583427922815, 
0.847701961671095, 0.925758597437626, 0.939714274771152, 0.159834844421743, 
0.963041043547006, 0.776261198965787, 0.924494606757626, 0.934594186658129, 
0.215513666953721, 0.965961526937137), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("cg00346985", "cg00566297", "cg02152233", "cg02855836", 
    "cg03043665"), c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01", 
    "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01")))

> dput(exp[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01 = c(7.65342121905285, 14.3511850042327, 
10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255, 9.44832324553208), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(5.09389393824392, 
12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252, 9.9623840324273
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01 = c(4.70168212029528, 10.1689338100564, 9.96839262629172, 
9.87305770150294, 9.75535162798678), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01 = c(7.99645936536463, 
13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992, 10.0652444551968
), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(5.13719199914349, 12.0367193976262, 10.8202555636581, 
10.3262700402849, 9.91216810777653)), row.names = c("ENSG00000121410", 
"ENSG00000175899", "ENSG00000128274", "ENSG00000094914", "ENSG00000081760"
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(triplets[1:5,])
structure(list(regionID = c("chr1:18481608-18481609", "chr1:149917809-149917810", 
"chr1:149917809-149917810", "chr1:149917809-149917810", "chr1:149917809-149917810"
), probeID = c("cg14356550", "cg04927502", "cg04927502", "cg04927502", 
"cg04927502"), target_symbol = c("KLHDC7A", "SV2A", "SV2A", "SV2A", 
"SV2A"), target = c("ENSG00000179023", "ENSG00000159164", "ENSG00000159164", 
"ENSG00000159164", "ENSG00000159164"), TF_symbol = c("MSC", "KLF7", 
"SP1", "SP2", "KLF12"), TF = c("ENSG00000178860", "ENSG00000118263", 
"ENSG00000185591", "ENSG00000167182", "ENSG00000118922"), distance_region_target_tss = c(625, 
33, 33, 33, 33), target_region = c("chr1:18480982-18486126", 
"chr1:149903318-149917844", "chr1:149903318-149917844", "chr1:149903318-149917844", 
"chr1:149903318-149917844"), met.IQR = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), RLM_DNAmGroup_pvalue = c(0.00624152331006544, 
0.00807308191339606, 0.011859989390711, 0.00762527378035482, 
0.00870334773123105), RLM_DNAmGroup_fdr = c(0.00624152331006544, 
0.0108791846640388, 0.011859989390711, 0.0108791846640388, 0.0108791846640388
), RLM_TF_pvalue = c(0.0198165113192696, 0.172314176184383, 0.588143772014052, 
0.07647903917541, 0.652169631413073), RLM_TF_fdr = c(0.0198165113192696, 
0.287190293640639, 0.652169631413073, 0.287190293640639, 0.652169631413073
), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_pvalue` = c(0.299031042745102, 0.604611631664618, 
0.678211833276852, 0.513130219522431, 0.461294793204991), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_fdr` = c(0.299031042745102, 
0.678211833276852, 0.678211833276852, 0.678211833276852, 0.678211833276852
), RLM_DNAmGroup_estimate = c(-0.52064632818464, -0.601377932594936, 
-0.572803265176227, -0.596365826313026, -0.595212073858527), 
    RLM_TF_estimate = c(0.294035665720224, 0.233365505940679, 
    0.0827930869675411, 0.229904946996618, -0.0807406502288581
    ), `RLM_DNAmGroup:TF_estimate` = c(-0.178568381402422, -0.124877097905908, 
    0.0916943232970155, -0.138792999736741, 0.170451760374313
    ), Model.quantile = c("Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", 
    "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model", "Robust Linear Model"
    ), Target_gene_DNAm_high_vs_Target_gene_DNAm_low_wilcoxon_pvalue = c(0.0188489288218801, 
    0.00756434356177548, 0.00756434356177548, 0.00756434356177548, 
    0.00756434356177548), TF_DNAm_high_vs_TF_DNAm_low_wilcoxon_pvalue = c(0.103017486454832, 
    0.991230272587984, 0.641713419479296, 0.70589647863005, 0.744364187932646
    ), `% of target genes not expressed in DNAm_low and DNAm_high` = c("0 %", 
    "0 %", "0 %", "0 %", "0 %"), DNAm_low_RLM_target_vs_TF_pvalue = c(0.0363032922123756, 
    0.188508617382668, 0.540145430623009, 0.0950814839121672, 
    0.679915291560102), DNAm_low_RLM_target_vs_TF_estimate = c(0.296132741981433, 
    0.232961111108474, 0.0965957533188939, 0.221791007792371, 
    -0.0772940745780587), DNAm_high_RLM_target_vs_TF_pvalue = c(0.22224740419026, 
    0.526649225195494, 0.267225694219024, 0.666917243782734, 
    0.492756808381384), DNAm_high_RLM_target_vs_TF_estimate = c(0.123844124235788, 
    0.104046456623531, 0.168547284367383, 0.0728392683223166, 
    0.097366177507758), DNAm.effect = c("ns", "ns", "ns", "ns", 
    "ns"), TF.role = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), model = c("promoter", "promoter", 
    "promoter", "promoter", "promoter")), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: FWIW that doesn't look like robust regression, it looks like plain old linear/least-squares regression ... ???

Comment: You are right. I tried `rlm <- sapply(seq(ncol(meth_subset)), function(i) rlm(meth_subset[, i] ~ exp_subset[, i]))` but it returned an empty list. Please kindly check my updated code.

Comment: I think so, provided you work out whatever other issues you're having. The other thing to keep in mind is that fitting models is not generally symmetric (i.e., fitting `y ~ x` and `x ~ y` will give different results, although some aspects such as R^2 will be the same - I don't think this will still hold for robust LM, though, as the 'robustness' will only be for variation in the response/dependent variable ... see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/which-robust-correlation-methods-are-actually-used

Comment: But why does the code return an empty list?

Comment: That's why I said "whatever other issues you're having".  I haven't had a chance to look into this yet.